Outlook access to email with imaplib with valid `access_token` and got AUTHENTICATE failed error
I am trying to access to outlook email with imaplib, here's the implementation:
import imaplib
import base64
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication

def get_access_token():
    tenant_id = '************************************'
    authority = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + tenant_id
    client_id = '************************************'
    client_secret = '************************************'
    scopes = ['https://outlook.office365.com/.default']
    app = ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id, authority=authority,
          client_credential = client_secret)
    ans = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scopes)
    return ans['access_token']

def generate_auth_string(user, token):
    auth_string = f'user={user}\1auth=Bearer {token}\1\1'
    auth_string = base64.b64encode(auth_string.encode()).decode()
    return auth_string

# IMAP AUTHENTICATE
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('outlook.office365.com')
user_email = "my_email@my_company_domain.ca"
access_token = get_access_token()
print(f"Access Token: {access_token}")  # Print the access token to check if it's correct

try:
    imap.authenticate("XOAUTH2", lambda _: generate_auth_string(user_email, access_token))
    imap.select('inbox')
except imaplib.IMAP4.error as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")

Now I am capable of getting valid access_token, unfortunately when call authenticate with token I got AUTHENTICATE failed error.
The error message is not really helpful. I searched online but didn't get instructions how to fix it? Can someone help to point out what is missing in the code or anything missing in Azure portal configuration? Thanks!

What are your scopes?  You probably need to specify the IMAP scopes, both in the registration and at token fetch time.

The scope is scopes = ['https://outlook.office365.com/.default'].
